# How to update lambda function code if the lambda code is uploaded to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

The lambda function code(zip file) is currently being got from my S3 bucket. However, after I change my code and replace the original zip file with updated code and then run update-stack, the lambda function code seems not change in the lambda console.

Is there any way to make it work?

My json template

```json
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
   
   "Parameters": {
    "storageS3Bucket": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "myBucket"
    }
  },
   "Resources": {
     
    "s3BucketImageStorage":{
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties" : {
          "BucketName" : {
              "Ref": "storageS3Bucket"
          }
        }
    },
     "getBannerHandler": {
       "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
       "Properties": {
         "FunctionName": "getBanner",
         "Handler": "getBanner.handler",
         "Role": {
           "Fn::ImportValue": {
             "Fn::Sub": "${RolesStack}-LambdaRoleArn"
           }
         },
         "Code": {
           "S3Bucket": {
             "Ref": "HandlerCodeS3Bucket"
           },
           "S3Key":"getBanner.zip"
         },
         "Runtime": "nodejs12.x"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have few options:

- Add file version or git commit hash to the  lambda zip file name so when you do CloudFormation update-stack you pass the new zip file name as parameters.
- Or use awscli to update the lambda function directly, but better to delete zip file first then upload it in case you want to use the same name to avoid S3 eventual consistency when replacing the same file.

Comment: Instead of git commit hash, consider an md5 hash of the code. That way, the code will only be redeployed when the code changes, not on every git commit.

Comment: Unless you are using a mono repo, git hash will also only change when the labmda code changes and it is easier to obtain